# Text on top of an image

Tags: html, css, image, text, overlay

I want to make a navigation bar, with each item having its own image with the name of the item written on top of that. So there should be a few images in a row, and each one has some text written on it. This is the row of images I got:

```
<div class="navigation" align="center">
<a href="link1"><img src="images/bn_blue.png" width="120" height="70" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="link2"><img src="images/bn_blue.png" width="120" height="70" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="link3"><img src="images/bn_blue.png" width="120" height="70" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="link4"><img src="images/bn_blue.png" width="120" height="70" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="link5"><img src="images/bn_blue.png" width="120" height="70" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="link6"><img src="images/bn_blue.png" width="120" height="70" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: That's probably not the best way to go try using the images as `background-image`s of the anchor links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="navigation" align="center">
<ul><li><a href="link2"><div style="background-image:url(images/bn_blue.png);width:120px;height:70px">xyz</div></a></li>
<li><a href="link2"><div style="background-image:url(images/bn_blue.png);width:120px;height:70px">xyz</div></a></li>
<li><a href="link2"><div style="background-image:url(images/bn_blue.png);width:120px;height:70px">xyz</div></a></li>
<li><a href="link2"><div style="background-image:url(images/bn_blue.png);width:120px;height:70px">xyz</div></a></li>
<li><a href="link2"><div style="background-image:url(images/bn_blue.png);width:120px;height:70px">xyz</div></a><li>
</ul>
</div> 
<style>
li
{
display:inline-block;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give each a href a class ie .home_bg etc.
Then in css add a

```
.home_bg {
background-image: url(/example/example.png)
}
```

do this for each image if they are different. Then in the html remove img tags

Comment: But then rhere is a div cotainer for each menu button, and then they aren't next to each other anymore

Comment: Don't add Div around each one see below

Comment: Use an ul to house each link in an li the add the class from above to each li. ensure the ul has a css rule to list-style: none; and for the ul li display: inline; should work find